# Calculating $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx$ using two variable integration?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The classic $e^{-x^2}$ is known for not being able to be integrated analitically but there are some ways of evaluating its Riemann integral.

I know that often people use residues theorem for calculating it bringing it to the complex plane, but I remember when I was taking a 2-variables course that the professor managed to calculate it using only double integrals (no complex stuff involved). I can't remember the way to do it for my life, though...

Does anyone know how to calculate this using double integration on the real $xy$ plane?

Comment: Do you believe $e^{x^2}$ is integrable over $0 < x <\infty$?

Comment: This integral in your question is clearly infinite. I think you're thinking of the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), where what you're looking for is both at that Wikipedia link and a number of questions here.

Comment: oops, exp(-x²), my bad.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates